# Add scroll to WIX Bundle help page

Tags: wix, themes, bundle, wix4

I have a custom Bundle's theme where I would like to change style of help page, since a lot of text does not fit in a standard window, It will be good to have scrolling. Is there any way to do this?

```
<Theme xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/thmutil">
    <Window ...>
        ...
        <Page Name="Help">
            <Label X="11" Y="80" Width="-11" Height="30" FontId="2" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.HelpHeader)</Label>
            <Label X="11" Y="112" Width="-11" Height="-35" FontId="3" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.HelpText)</Label>
            <Button Name="HelpCloseButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">
                <Text>#(loc.HelpCloseButton)</Text>
                <CloseWindowAction />
            </Button>
        </Page>
        ...
```

Example of code was taken from [https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix/.../Bal/wixstdba/Resources/RtfTheme.xml](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix/blob/e570ce580afa981d3cf7750bea1d129309b48a06/src/ext/Bal/wixstdba/Resources/RtfTheme.xml#L5)

Expect to get result like in MSI help page:

[image]

Comment: Window element (Thmutil extension) as well does not work with parameters: AutoResize="yes" MinimumWidth="[VAL]" MinimumHeight="[VAL]"